# How to update a table using a CTE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

As an example in Sql server I can achieve this easily like so:

```
WITH cte_person AS
(
     SELECT PersonalIdentificationNumber, PersonName
     FROM Employee
)
UPDATE Person
SET Person.PersonName = cte.PersonName
FROM cte_person cte
WHERE Person.PersonalIdentificationNumber = cte.PersonalIdentificationNumber
```

But how do I achieve this in Oracle using a CTE specifically or is there no support for this? I have searched around and havn't found a satisfying answer. Most seem to wrap the CTE in an inline select statement.

Comment: Oracle does not allow this syntax.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to do.  As a note:  Your code is not valid SQL Server code either so it is totally unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you asked how to use a CTE in `UPDATE`, then:

```
update person p set
  p.name = (with cte_person as
              (select personalidentificationnumber, name
               from employee
              )
            select c.name
            from cte_person c
            where c.personalidentificationnumber = p.personalidentificationnumber
           )
  where exists (select null
                from employee e
                where e.personalidentificationnumber = p.personalidentificationnumber
               );
```

Though, `merge` is somewhat simpler as you don't have to additionally check which rows to update (see the `exists` clause in `update` example):

```
merge into person p
  using (with cte_person as
              (select personalidentificationnumber, name
               from employee
              )
         select c.personalidentificationnumber,
                c.name
         from cte_person c
        ) x
  on (p.personalidentificationnumber = x.personalidentificationnumber)
  when matched then update set 
    p.name = x.name;
```

---

However, this can be simplified - see code Ankit posted (but - as I said - if you want to know how to use a CTE, then that's how).

Comment: Happy to see the last line of your answer. Means a lot.

Comment: While Ankit's answer is indeed simpler in this case. The question is on how to do this with a CTE specifically, which unfortunately he didn't do. 

I'm happy that you took the time to thoroughly read the question, I'll test this out and if it works as expected and there's no cleaner syntax for this you'll get the answer point aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not allow for directly updating a CTE (unlike SQL Server, which allows it).  If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to update the names in the `Person` table using the names from the `Employee` table, based on matching IDs.  One way to do this in Oracle uses a correlated subquery.

```sql
UPDATE Person p
SET Name = (SELECT e.Name FROM Employee e
            WHERE e.PersonalIdentificationNumber = p.PersonalIdentificationNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I gave you a point for specifying that Oracle doens't support this syntax but the question is on how to use a CTE.

Comment: If I need to update each column matching its own specific condition only - are separate UPDATE operators the only way in Oracle? If I use MERGE + CASE - then I will have to update all columns, with a new value or with its current value, not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE statement for this -

```
MERGE INTO Person p
USING Employee e
ON (p.PersonalIdentificationNumber = e.PersonalIdentificationNumber)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
             UPDATE
                SET p.Name = e.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Ankit but I am already aware of the merge syntax by itself. The question was how to do this using a CTE.

Comment: _"The question was how to do this using a CTE."_  I'm curious about the insistance on using a CTE when there  are better solutions.